# Jquery - Rearrange div based on an array of select values

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I need help completing my feature, I think I have a good start but some troubles finishing it!

I have multiple divs on my page and each one is containing a select box.
I have a button to sort the divs based on the value of each select.

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1wj6spd/) with my code and some comments.

I will also put the code here:

**JS**

```
$('.sort-priority').click(function(){
  var priorityValues = $('select.js-priority').val();

   var arr = [];
   var i= 0;
   $('select.js-priority').each(function() {
     arr[i++] = parseInt(this.value);
   });

  console.log(arr); //Get an array of all my select default values [2, 0, 1, 0]
  arr.sort();
  console.log(arr); //Sorted the array the way I want, so all the 0 values first... [0, 0, 1, 2]

  /* I cant figure out out how to rearrange my divs on the page, so I show the divs in the order of the sorted array of select values. 
  In this example the first box would be box2 (select value of 0), then box4 (select value of 0), box3 (select value of 1) and finally box1 (select value of 2).*/
});
```

Im a bit lost on how to manipulate my html to change the box ordering based on my array ?! If anyone could help, would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- On click of the button, append the sorted boxes.
- Sorted boxes is base on getting all of them, using `get()` to get a normal array, and calling sort.

  - Sorting is done by finding the select in each box, getting their values, and subtracting them so it sorts ascending.

```js
$('.sort-priority').on('click', function(){
  $('.content').append($('.box').get().sort(function(a,b){
    return $('select', a).val() - $('select', b).val();
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="sort-priority">Order by priority</button>
<br /><br />
<div class="content">

  <div class="box" id="box1" data-box="1">
    <select class="js-priority" id="box1-priority">
      <option value="0">Priority 0</option>
      <option value="1">Priority 1</option>
      <option value="2" selected="selected">Priority 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box2" data-box="2">
    <select class="js-priority" id="box2-priority">
      <option value="0" selected ="selected">Priority 0</option>
      <option value="1">Priority 1</option>
      <option value="2">Priority 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box3" data-box="3">
    <select class="js-priority" id="box3-priority">
      <option value="0">Priority 0</option>
      <option value="1" selected ="selected">Priority 1</option>
      <option value="2">Priority 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box4" data-box="4">
    <select class="js-priority" id="box4-priority">
      <option value="0" selected ="selected">Priority 0</option>
      <option value="1">Priority 1</option>
      <option value="2">Priority 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Oh my, I guess I was overcomplicating my life with my array of values !
I guess I will read more on the sort() function, thanks a lot man

Comment: Google "Array.prototype.sort" and look for the MDN page for a reference.

Answer (score 0):

**[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maheerali/koncvgua/)**. I just created an `array` of object which will contain value of select and its `parentNode`. You can `sort()` it by value and then `append` the parentNode of sorted array to container

```
$('.sort-priority').click(function(){
    var priorityValues = $('select.js-priority').val();

    var arr = [];
  var i= 0;
  $('select.js-priority').each(function() {
    arr[i++] = {value:parseInt(this.value),parent:this.parentNode};
  });

  console.log(arr); //Get an array of all my select edfault values [2, 0, 1, 0]
  arr = arr.sort((a,b) => a.value - b.value);
  arr.forEach(item => {
    document.querySelector('.content').appendChild(item.parent);
  })

  console.log(arr);
```